# Change images in ImageView with timer when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-imageview

I want to change 20 images inside an ImageView with timer (1sec delay).
Can someone help me? I tried **postdelayed runnable method** but my **Activity** is not functioning well (getting crushed 2 out of 10 clicks) when I put 17 images in my xml file (17 ImageViews). Each images has a max size of 230kb.
Can someone help me using another method? My code is too long for I use switch case. Can someone post any sample of your code it will really helps. Thanks.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal, PID: 32031
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException:
    Unable to start activity
        ComponentInfo{com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal/com.example.computer.mathkiddofinal.grade_level.topics.gradeFour_PlaceValue}:
            android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25:
                Error inflating class <unknown>
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
```

Here a sample of my code it's about 20 ImageViews. I only posted 2 ImageView for example.

```
public class gradeFour_PlaceValue extends Activity {

int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_grade_four__place_value);

    final Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final ImageView[] images = {(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1),
                    (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im2)};
            v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    images[count].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    switch (count){
                        case 0:
                            images[1].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            images[0].setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            break;
                        ...
```

my xml layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/place1">

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"

    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="179dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im1"
    android:visibility="gone"
   android:background="@drawable/place1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im2"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place2" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im3"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place3" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im4"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place4" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/im5"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place5" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im6"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place6" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im7"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place7" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/im8"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place8" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/im9"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place9" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/im10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place10" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/im11"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place11" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im12"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place12" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im13"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place13" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/im14"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place14" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/im15"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/place15" />
```

Comment: Please post related part of your code and crash logcat.

Comment: I think it crashes due to OutOfMemoryError as you have 20 images...

Comment: @HusseinElFeky that's the first thing i'm worrying about, what can i do??

Comment: @Lynerd I think I have got a very simple nice idea, but I have a question. You are trying to create something like an automatic slideshow, right?

Comment: @HusseinElFeky close, but i really want is to animate 20 images, those are like frames, like an gif but i'm going to put an audio while the images is animating.

Comment: @Lynerd The error says there is a problem with xml. Sorry again, can you post your `R.layout.activity_grade_four__place_value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a file called `images_slideshow` or whatever you want in your drawable folder:**

```
<animation-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image5" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image6" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image7" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image8" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image9" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image10" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image11" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image12" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image13" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image14" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image15" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image16" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image17" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image18" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image19" android:duration="1000" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image20" android:duration="1000" />
</animation-list>
```

This will shuffle your ImageView every 1 second, you can change the duration if you want from the `android:duration` attribute of each one of them. By setting the `android:oneshot` attribute of the list to true, it will cycle just once then stop and hold on the last frame. If it is set false then the animation will loop.

**Declare your views before onCreate():**

```
ImageView imageViews;
AnimationDrawable imagesAnimation;
```

**Add this in your onCreate():**

```
imageViews = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.im1);
imageViews.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images_slideshow);
imagesAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageViews.getBackground();

imageViews.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (imagesAnimation.isRunning()) {
                imagesAnimation.stop();
            } else {
                imagesAnimation.start();
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

You can now start and pause your images animation onTouch of the ImageView. You can change its logic like starting and pausing it through the onClick of a button.

Documentation: [AnimationDrawable | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html)

Give it a try. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() 
{
    int i = 0;

    public void run() 
    {
            image1.setImageResource(imageArray[i]);

            i++;
            if (i > imageArray.length - 1) 
            {
                i = 0;

            }
            Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(DashBordActivity.this, R.anim.anim1);
            image1.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 3000); // for interval...
        }

    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); // for initial delay..
```

Comment: i need to put my images in an array? or the anim1 is the folder?

Comment: i'm getting a lot of errors. there is no imageview to declare?

Comment: imageArray is the array of images i.e resource image, image1 is the imageview. anim1 is the animation effect whatever you want to show. if you not show any animation you can ignore Animation code.

Comment: thank you sir, also how can i check if the animation ends? i want to do something after the animation ends. removecallbacks? can you help me xD thank you for the help

Comment: it's now working, but i want it to only run once. how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Visibility.GONE` to hide ImageViews in your layout.xml (`R.layout.activity_grade_four__place_value`) and Java code (`gradeFour_PlaceValue`).

I think you should use `visibility="invisible"` in the xml and `images[n].setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` in the Java code.

Because `Visibility.GONE` means the View is absent from the layout. So you are using RelativeLayout as the parent ViewGroup and the ImageViews from number two to the last are rely on their position to the first ImageView (`im1`),

```
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/im1"
```

that they are unable to determine their positions when the first ImageView is absent (`Visibility.GONE`).

When you use `Visibility.INVISIBLE`, their existence in the layout haven't gone and just their visibility become invisible.

I hope it helps.